# Cannot retrieve Outlook.com mail on Client app. ( No matter which) on 14.04

Tags: thunderbird, email, evolution, imap

I'm experiencing a really strange behaviour of my 14.04 trusty tahr.
I have several email accounts ( personal, work, university etc) and so i prefer to manage them all together with a desktop app.
I tried to put up my accounts on Thunderbird which i always relied on, all of them are working fine except for outlook.com mail. Outlook seems to have problem connecting to the imap server ( error message like : disconnected by peer or similar). It cannot download folders ( just few ones) neither sync mails (it syncs just a few old mails) and then stops. 
After i double-checked my settings ( working fine on windows thunderbird, android phone and iphone), i tried to move to other clients, like k-mail,geary, evolution. And all of them had the same problem. So now i run out all the clients i knew and i still cannot read my outlook.com mails on ubuntu. Can someone help me? any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [Outlook.com is having IMAP connectivity problems at the moment](https://portal.office.com/servicestatus).

It still works in Windows because the desktop Outlook client uses their proprietary Outlook Activesync protocol and not IMAP. Your Outlook app is probably doing the same.

It's only things that use IMAP that are down.

Comment: But the user said it works fine on Windows and Android. This seems to be an issue with the application, and not the service.

Comment: Were they using IMAP on Windows and Android? Outlook and apps are probably using the proprietary Exchange protocol and would therefore be unaffected by IMAP issues.